# Add Sub-Total in Shopping Cart

Tags: asp.net, razor, shopping-cart

I made a View `ShoppingCart` in ASP.NET MVC 4. I completely created a textbox for ProductName, Price, and Quantity. In `Quantity` label, I used `Ajax` to create a button for User can type and update quanity of product. Now I want to create a `Sub-Total` for each `Product`. Could you help me to do as a favor ?

Summary of Shopping Cart:

```
@{int ix = 0;}

    @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
    {
        <tr id="row-@item.ShoppingCartItemID">

            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Product.Name, "Details", "Bike", new {id = item.ShoppingCartItemID},null)
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Product.ListPrice
            </td>

             <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CartItems[ix].Quantity, new {Styles = "width:3px; text-align:right; size:2" })
            </td>

            <td>
                <a href="#" class="RefreshQuantity" data-id="@item.ShoppingCartItemID" data-txt-id="CartItems_@(ix)__Quantity" >Update</a>
                &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                @Html.ActionLink("Remove","RemoveCart","ShoppingCart", new {id = item.ShoppingCartItemID},null)

            </td>
            <td>
               //Sub-Total ???
            </td>

    </tr>
    ix++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it easier to use some existing shopping cart? For example, [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/)